# Slider is working fine, but the pause is not

Tags: javascript

Anybody knows what is the issue here? Looking to pause the slider when mouse is on it. I can not figure out what is wrong with it. slider works, but yet it does not pause.

```
function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}

var slideIndex = 0;
var timer = null;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    var timer = setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
    mouseOver = clearTimeout(timer);
    mouseOut = setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
```

Comment: You `clearTimeout` has no effect as you set a new timeout just after. Seems that `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` have no action here.

Comment: You need to add eventlisteners for `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: mouseOver = clearTimeout(timer);  ??? You may add the mouseover event to the Slider and then, you move the mouse over it, the mouseover fires. This is not handle that event like this.